# Trying to sort list and print the result prints "built-in method sort of list object"

Tags: python, list

```
x = [1,2,1,2,4]
x = x.sort
print(x)
```

Output: `<built-in method sort of list object at 0x79b320c6edc0>`

Neither it is getting sorted nor printed.

Comment: x.sort is the method. You need to ***call*** the method:  x.sort()

Comment: But you don't want to save the return value, which is None. The method sorts the list in place.

Answer (score 0):

The sort() method in Python sorts the list in-place and returns None. So, when you do x = x.sort(), you are assigning the value of None to x. Therefore, x is no longer a list, and when you try to print it, you see the output indicating that it's None.

To fix this, you should use the sort() method directly without reassigning it to x. Here's the corrected code:

```
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
x.sort()
print(x)
```

This can also be achieved by:

```
x = [1, 2, 1, 2, 4]
sorted_x = sorted(x)
print(sorted_x)
```

Here, X stores the value if you want to use this in future. This way, the original list x remains unchanged, and sorted_x contains the sorted version.

Comment: Your explanation is only half correct. You are neglecting that they didn't even call `sort` and what was assigned to `x` was not `None`, but the `sort` method itself.

Comment: Sorry for the earlier mistake - I am still new at this. Edited it just now. Thanks.